# I have 2 tables and I need to use SQL to return non matching data/columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with same number of columns. tablea has 5 rows and tableb has 4 rows with 2 matching rows and 3 non matching rows. I need to return all 3 non matching columns/data

The query below only returns the non matching column in table and not all the non matching columns. I'am trying to return non matching rows 3,4,5 . see table below

```
select * 
from tablea 
where not exists (select * from tableb 
                  where tableb.id = tablea.id)


Table a:

id   contact    name  address  city postalcode country
———————————————
1     ab       aa   123    hd  12 usa
2     as      bb    321    hh  23 mex
3     av      cc   571    hn  123 mex
4     as      ww   457    bd   57  uk
5     chat    xx   23     dh  123 fin


Table b:

id   contact    name  address  city postalcode country
————————————————
1     ab      aa    123      hd    12   usa
2     as      bb    321      hh    23   mex
3     ad      ah    3200     res   321  mex
4     ash     bb    457      hsj   1223 uk
```

Comment: *returns the non matching column in table and not all the non matching columns* this is a contradiction - re-read what you've typed.

Comment: Please share sample data and desired results, also share your RDBMS as syntax varies product by product. Likely you can use something like `SELECT * FROM tableA EXCEPT /*or MINUS*/ SELECT * FROM tableB`. We can provide a more exact answer though if you can give more information.

Comment: that is what im looking for. but im trying to see if im able to find it also with joins?

Comment: Using *exists* is usually the most performant way, and your query would appear to do exactly as you describe.

Comment: Your sample data does not have a *customerid* column - and assuming it's the *id* column your data does not match the situation you describe.

Comment: it's id not customerid. my query only returns row 5 from tablea . I need to return row 3,4, and 5 as they are non matching in both tables

Comment: Then it looks like your correlation should be on the *contact* column....?

Comment: yes that would be

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on what rows you want exactly, as your text is kinda contradictionary, but if you want the 3 not matching rows from tableb this is what you need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM tableb WHERE customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid FROM tablea)
```

If you want the ones not matching from tablea, you just need to change tablea with tableb and vice versa.

If you want all not matching, combine both options:

```
SELECT * FROM tablea, tableb WHERE tablea.customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid from tableb) AND tableb.customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid from tablea)
```

Comment: he wants only the non matching cplums, and we dün't know how the result should be

Comment: I added tables I need the non matching data from both table

Comment: Then the SQL with NOT EXISTS should be the right way to do it. What exactly is not working there? Can you please add the outcome you get and the outcome you want to get as well.